# Question Regarding Node JS App Deployment on Heroku

Tags: heroku, github-actions

I have a nodejs application that I need  deploy on Heroku
that Connects with a mongodb Database
Now I need to host this on heroku and have a dot env file which contains the creds (which contains DB_URL, DB_NAME , DB PASS)

So should I add .env into gitignore and the push the code into github repo or don't add it to gitignore and then push. Because I will be connecting this repo into heroku for deployment

Comment: Your `.env` and `node_modules/` should always have been in your `.gitignore`. If you have already committed them, adding them to `.gitignore` will not be sufficient. You'll need to remove them, e.g. with `git rm --cached` and then commit. Note that you may also want to generate new credentials as the current ones will be in your repository history if you saved them there.

Comment: And please read [ask]. I'm not seeing any deployment issues here as your title suggests.